# CloudKit Fetch all User records

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I would like to fetch all the users that are working in the same public default container for my app.
Is it possible to fetch all user IDs?

When I try to do this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"]; // to search for all the records
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Users" predicate:predicate];
[_publicDB performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Error handling for failed fetch from public database
        NSLog(@"Error:%@", error);
    }
    else {
        // Display the fetched records
        NSLog(@"Users: %@", results);
    }
}];
```

I get an error like this:

```
Error:<CKError 0x7f9c6b7331f0: "Permission Failure" (10/2007); server message = "Can't query system types"; uuid = 9CBA8EB0-D9DC-46B2-BDF4-10C036599642; container ID = "iCloud.com.xxx.xxx.MyApp">
```

Do you know how can I achieve this? I want to know from a client perspective (iOS) what are the other users that use my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Users recordType is a special recordType which you cannot query. If you want to perform this sort of queries, then you should create your own recordType and insert a record for every user.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I was also thinking about a new  recordType that would store indexed user ID's. Thanks for quick reply.
To be honest, the User recordType should be query-able to avoid data duplication like in my case ;)

Comment: In the past that table also contained a first and last name. I guess that for privacy reasons querying Users was limited.

Comment: Once your CloudKit app is in production, can you see the iCloud user ID for every `User` that uses your app in the CloudKit dashboard?